# Spring WebClient setting some fields to null when they are not null in the response body

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I have domain class

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Document
public class Bar {

    @Id
    private String id;


    private List<String> owners;
    private List<String> cFeatures; 

    private Integer age;
    private String color;

}
```

I am using below code to invoke API to get data in Bar object:

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
    Mono<Bar> prop = webClient.get()
                    .uri("/bars/"+id)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Bar.class).log("find by id")
```

The problem is that I get cFeatures as null even though original JSON response 
has:
"cFeatures":["custom feature one", ""]

but owners list gets correct value even though owners also has empty string value  in the list (not sure if thats the source of this bug)

so Bar object has:
cFeatures: null

Is this a bug in Webclient or am I missing something ? I spent whole day on this but no fix yet.

Comment: Please provide full information, Just by looking into web-client and POJO no one can tell what is missing,

Comment: try this @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) @Serialization

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with lombok. Lombok was generating setter method:

setCFeatures

but jackson expects setter:

setcFeatures  which it does not find and hence null value for cFeatures.

Answer (score 0):

It can be helpful if you make sure your `POJO` has the correct annotation style. For example, use `jsonscheme2pojo.org` and choose `"Json"` as your source type and `"Jackson 2.x"` as your annotation style. That should make the problem disappear. I was stuck at first by the same problem because I used a `Gson`-annotated `POJO`.